# JavaFX WebEngine generating StringIndexOutOfBoundsException, what's wrong?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-webengine

I have a little experiment project using JavaFX that has a button and a WebView. When the button is pressed, a website is loaded:

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

public class Controller {
    @FXML private Button theButton;
    @FXML private WebView theWebView;


    @FXML
    protected void loadWebSite(ActionEvent event) {
        theWebView.getEngine().load("https://dashman.tech");
    }
}
```

When that happens, I get these errors:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.drawString(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:960)
    at com.sun.webkit.graphics.GraphicsDecoder.decode(GraphicsDecoder.java:290)
    at com.sun.webkit.graphics.WCRenderQueue.decode(WCRenderQueue.java:91)
    at com.sun.webkit.graphics.WCRenderQueue.decode(WCRenderQueue.java:102)
    at com.sun.webkit.graphics.WCImage.flushRQ(WCImage.java:52)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.RTImage.lambda$getPixelBuffer$77(RTImage.java:163)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 7
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.drawString(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:960)
    at com.sun.webkit.graphics.GraphicsDecoder.decode(GraphicsDecoder.java:290)
    at com.sun.webkit.graphics.WCRenderQueue.decode(WCRenderQueue.java:91)
    at com.sun.webkit.graphics.WCRenderQueue.decode(WCRenderQueue.java:102)
    at com.sun.webkit.graphics.WCImage.flushRQ(WCImage.java:52)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.RTImage.lambda$getPixelBuffer$77(RTImage.java:163)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 6
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.drawString(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:960)
    at com.sun.webkit.graphics.GraphicsDecoder.decode(GraphicsDecoder.java:290)
    at com.sun.webkit.graphics.WCRenderQueue.decode(WCRenderQueue.java:91)
    at com.sun.webkit.graphics.WCRenderQueue.decode(WCRenderQueue.java:102)
    at com.sun.webkit.graphics.WCImage.flushRQ(WCImage.java:52)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.RTImage.lambda$getPixelBuffer$77(RTImage.java:163)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any ideas why? How do I prevent it? The site seems to be loading fine. Other sites don't generate those errors.

Answer (score 1):

When I test this on Mac OSX with jdk1.8.0_131 I get a slightly different error with a different stack with native methods on the stack:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCFontImpl.getGlyphsAndAdvances(WCFontImpl.java:120)
    at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.twkDidReceiveData(Native Method)
    at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.notifyDidReceiveData(URLLoader.java:844)
    at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.lambda$didReceiveData$102(URLLoader.java:819)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
```

and when I set the logging level for `com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCFontImpl` to *all*, I get the following information:

```
c.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCFontImpl - str='ð' (length=2), from=0, to=4, rtl=false
c.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCFontImpl - str='ð©' (length=4), from=0, to=7, rtl=false
c.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCFontImpl - str='ð' (length=3), from=0, to=6, rtl=false
```

When I look at the strings it seems that the length in the logging message is the correct number of characters, but the arguments for *from* and *to* seem not to take into account, that the strings contain multibyte characters. These wrong values are used for a substring call which then causes the exception. I could not find out which font is making trouble here.

So I think, that the site loads some font which is damaged or not correct. The browser engine ignores these errors, although dumping out the stack trace and that's why the page is working nonetheless - perhaps not displaying something in the desired font.

Why do you have a different stacktrace? I'm not sure, this might be because of you using a different OS or a different Java version?

And I do not think you can prevent this, only if you are responsible for that site and check the used fonts.